# Why does my Time Machine backup fail?

Tags: macos, time-machine

I am trying to backup my Laptop to my UnRAID server. Now the third time it failed and displayed this message:

[image]

My backup is  650 GB big and contains 1.6 million files. May this be the problem? Or is it UnRAID?

These are the messages from the Console containing "backupd":

```
5/28/12 12:01:34.589 AM com.apple.backupd: Copied 159.4 GB of 613.3 GB, 1008543 of 1447860 items
5/28/12 12:38:21.632 AM com.apple.backupd: Error: (-36) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album/01 Petite apocalypse.mp3 to /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/***’s MacBook Pro/2012-05-27-163146.inProgress/07D7698B-9DBF-46A3-A070-A0B58F160EED/Macintosh HD/Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album
5/28/12 12:38:21.973 AM com.apple.backupd: Error: (-36) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album/02 L'esprit de vos cimeterres.mp3 to /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/***’s MacBook Pro/2012-05-27-163146.inProgress/07D7698B-9DBF-46A3-A070-A0B58F160EED/Macintosh HD/Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album
5/28/12 12:38:22.012 AM com.apple.backupd: Error: (-36) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album/03 A vouloir toucher Dieu....mp3 to /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/***’s MacBook Pro/2012-05-27-163146.inProgress/07D7698B-9DBF-46A3-A070-A0B58F160EED/Macintosh HD/Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album
5/28/12 12:38:22.064 AM com.apple.backupd: Error: (-36) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album/04 AKH.mp3 to /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/***’s MacBook Pro/2012-05-27-163146.inProgress/07D7698B-9DBF-46A3-A070-A0B58F160EED/Macintosh HD/Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album
5/28/12 12:38:22.110 AM com.apple.backupd: Error: (-36) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album/05 Musique de la jungle.mp3 to /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/***’s MacBook Pro/2012-05-27-163146.inProgress/07D7698B-9DBF-46A3-A070-A0B58F160EED/Macintosh HD/Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album
5/28/12 12:38:22.169 AM com.apple.backupd: Error: (-36) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album/06 Nid de guêpes.mp3 to /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/***’s MacBook Pro/2012-05-27-163146.inProgress/07D7698B-9DBF-46A3-A070-A0B58F160EED/Macintosh HD/Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album
5/28/12 12:38:22.227 AM com.apple.backupd: Error: (-36) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album/07 Ecoeuré.mp3 to /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/***’s MacBook Pro/2012-05-27-163146.inProgress/07D7698B-9DBF-46A3-A070-A0B58F160EED/Macintosh HD/Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album
5/28/12 12:38:22.296 AM com.apple.backupd: Error: (-36) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album/08 Nerf de glace.mp3 to /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/***’s MacBook Pro/2012-05-27-163146.inProgress/07D7698B-9DBF-46A3-A070-A0B58F160EED/Macintosh HD/Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album
5/28/12 12:38:22.339 AM com.apple.backupd: Error: (-36) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album/09 Une journée chez le diable.mp3 to /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/***’s MacBook Pro/2012-05-27-163146.inProgress/07D7698B-9DBF-46A3-A070-A0B58F160EED/Macintosh HD/Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album
5/28/12 12:38:22.383 AM com.apple.backupd: Error: (-36) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album/10 Paranoïa.mp3 to /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/***’s MacBook Pro/2012-05-27-163146.inProgress/07D7698B-9DBF-46A3-A070-A0B58F160EED/Macintosh HD/Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album
5/28/12 12:38:22.425 AM com.apple.backupd: Error: (-36) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album/11 J'voulais dire.mp3 to /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/***’s MacBook Pro/2012-05-27-163146.inProgress/07D7698B-9DBF-46A3-A070-A0B58F160EED/Macintosh HD/Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album
5/28/12 12:38:22.476 AM com.apple.backupd: Error: (-36) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album/12 Bionic Mc's.mp3 to /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/***’s MacBook Pro/2012-05-27-163146.inProgress/07D7698B-9DBF-46A3-A070-A0B58F160EED/Macintosh HD/Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album
5/28/12 12:38:22.514 AM com.apple.backupd: Error: (-36) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album/13 Esprit beatstreet.mp3 to /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/***’s MacBook Pro/2012-05-27-163146.inProgress/07D7698B-9DBF-46A3-A070-A0B58F160EED/Macintosh HD/Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album
5/28/12 12:38:22.558 AM com.apple.backupd: Error: (-36) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album/14 Ancient scriptures.mp3 to /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/***’s MacBook Pro/2012-05-27-163146.inProgress/07D7698B-9DBF-46A3-A070-A0B58F160EED/Macintosh HD/Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album
5/28/12 12:38:22.611 AM com.apple.backupd: Error: (-36) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album/15 Aux âmes offencées.mp3 to /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/***’s MacBook Pro/2012-05-27-163146.inProgress/07D7698B-9DBF-46A3-A070-A0B58F160EED/Macintosh HD/Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album
5/28/12 12:38:22.658 AM com.apple.backupd: Error: (-36) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album/16 Au minimum.mp3 to /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/***’s MacBook Pro/2012-05-27-163146.inProgress/07D7698B-9DBF-46A3-A070-A0B58F160EED/Macintosh HD/Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album
5/28/12 12:38:22.704 AM com.apple.backupd: Error: (-36) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album/17 Rimes sévères.mp3 to /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/***’s MacBook Pro/2012-05-27-163146.inProgress/07D7698B-9DBF-46A3-A070-A0B58F160EED/Macintosh HD/Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Black album
5/28/12 12:38:22.744 AM com.apple.backupd: Error: (-36) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Electro Cypher to /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/***’s MacBook Pro/2012-05-27-163146.inProgress/07D7698B-9DBF-46A3-A070-A0B58F160EED/Macintosh HD/Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton
5/28/12 12:38:22.745 AM com.apple.backupd: Stopping backup.
5/28/12 12:38:22.745 AM com.apple.backupd: Error: (-8062) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/***/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Music/Akhenaton/Electro Cypher/01 DJ Ralph _ Fat bass.mp3 to (null)
5/28/12 12:38:22.963 AM com.apple.backupd: Copied 1017720 files (183.5 GB) from volume Macintosh HD.
5/28/12 12:38:22.963 AM com.apple.backupd: Copy stage failed with error:11
5/28/12 12:38:34.384 AM com.apple.backupd: Backup failed with error: 11
5/28/12 12:38:43.490 AM com.apple.backupd: Ejected Time Machine disk image.
5/28/12 12:38:43.920 AM com.apple.backupd: Ejected Time Machine network volume.
5/28/12 1:30:27.562 AM com.apple.backupd: Starting standard backup
5/28/12 1:30:27.642 AM com.apple.backupd: Attempting to mount network destination URL: afp://;AUTH=No%20User%20Authent@Tower.local/Time%20Capsule
5/28/12 1:30:33.177 AM com.apple.backupd: Mounted network destination at mountpoint: /Volumes/Time Capsule using URL: afp://;AUTH=No%20User%20Authent@Tower.local/Time%20Capsule
5/28/12 1:30:54.096 AM com.apple.backupd: QUICKCHECK ONLY; FILESYSTEM DIRTY
5/28/12 1:30:54.586 AM com.apple.backupd: Runtime corruption detected on /Volumes/Time Capsule/***’s MacBook Pro.sparsebundle (fsck_hfs -q termination status: 3)
5/28/12 1:30:54.890 AM com.apple.backupd: Network destination already mounted at: /Volumes/Time Capsule
5/28/12 10:50:02.546 AM com.apple.backupd: Recovery backup requested by user.
5/28/12 11:15:54.240 AM com.apple.backupd: Backup failed because the network destination disk was ejected or disconnected unexpectedly!
5/28/12 11:15:54.281 AM com.apple.backupd: Failed to remove file://localhost/Volumes/Time%20Capsule/***%E2%80%99s%20MacBook%20Pro.purgeable/, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "“***’s MacBook Pro.purgeable” couldn’t be removed." UserInfo=0x10293f4d0 {NSFilePath=/Volumes/Time Capsule/***’s MacBook Pro.purgeable, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Remove
), NSUnderlyingError=0x102931720 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Socket is not connected"}
5/28/12 11:15:55.284 AM com.apple.backupd: Backup failed with error: 26
```

Comment: I added the messages to my question. Thanks for the input!

Comment: `Runtime corruption detected` is quite obvious. Can you try if the backup works on a new partition on the NAS? Have you been using the same backup for multiple versions of OS X before?

Comment: It is a new partition of the NAS. I just formatted it. Maybe I should try to do it again? Or is the disk defect? No, it is a new Time Machine backup.

Comment: Depending on what user name you censored, it's possible your NAS can't handle file paths over a certain length, e.g. 250 characters, like most Windows programs.

Comment: That would be weird... its a [UnRAID](http://lime-technology.com/) server based on Slackware. This would really supprise me if this was the case.